# Solidity: Why is this simple storage contract not working?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, go-ethereum, evm

I'm practicing by creating a simple storage contract, but I can't store or retrieve values from the array "numbers." The uint "structID" does not increment and function "testRetrieve" only returns 0 for the correct indexes.

The fact that "StructID" is not incrementing leads me to believe that the issue lies in the function "store."  However, after reading multiple questions here at SO and online tutorials/documentation, I am still stumped.

Does anyone know why this contract will not store data?

```
contract testStruct {

   uint public structID;

    struct SomeStruct {
        uint[] numbers;
    }

    SomeStruct[] someStructs;

    function store(uint _numbers, uint entryID) public {

        SomeStruct memory someStruct;
        someStructs.push(someStruct);

        someStructs[entryID].numbers.push(_numbers);

        structID++;

    }

    function testRetrieve(uint entryID, uint test) public view returns (uint) {

        return someStructs[entryID].numbers[test];

    }
}
```

EDIT: For the functions above, I am calling all the functions from a geth console on a private blockchain. For "testRetrieve", I am testing the function with "0" provided for both "entryID" and "test" to specify the very first entry in the array.

Function “store” sends a transaction when called.

EDIT:

The issue was gas.  Even though my private net has a low gas price, giving the transaction 200000 gas (the store function costs around 104000) over the default value of 90000 on my net allowed it to be successful.

Comment: It's impossible to know what's going wrong without seeing the code that's calling the functions, but my guess would be that either you're not sending a transaction (using `call` instead of `send`/`sendTransaction`) on the client, or you are sending a transaction but it's failing (e.g. specifying an `entryID` that's out of bounds of your `someStructs` array).

Comment: In terms of code that is calling the functions, I am calling them from a geth console on a private blockchain.  Also, the "store" function sends a transaction upon calling it, but does not store any data.  To test retrieval, I am using "0" for both "entryID" and "test" to specify the very first entry in the array.

Comment: Okay, new guess: the transaction has neither succeeded nor failed because it's not getting mined? I assume you know that `store` sends a transaction because you're seeing a transaction hash? If you call `eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash)`, was the transaction actually mined into a block (is there a block number)?

Comment: The transaction does have an associated block number.  by the way, can you see the code I've posted above?

Comment: I can see the contract code, if that's what you mean.

Comment: My only other guesses are around the address being wrong or the deployed version of the contract not matching the code you've shared here. Could you try adding something like `function test() public pure returns (uint256) { return 42; }` and verifying that you can call `test` successfully?

Comment: I’ve added the simple return function and verified that I can receive a returned value

Comment: Then I'm a bit stumped. The contract code works fine (I tested in Remix just to make sure), so presumably the issue is outside of that. If you can package everything else up (how you're starting geth, how you're deploying the contract, the exact code you're using to call the functions, etc.), I'll try to reproduce it.

Comment: If it adds more insight, if I alter the strict for a single value or byte32 as opposed to an array, the single value stores and retrieves correctly. It’s only after attempting to append an array inside the strict where things don’t work.

Comment: Oh, what about gas? We checked that the transaction got mined, but we didn't check for its result... perhaps you ran out of gas. (The fact that you can make a smaller change but fail to make a larger change makes me wonder about that.) Have you tried supplying more gas?

Comment: FWIW, Remix tells me the `store` call consumes 109,366 gas. Try 200,000 to be safe.

Comment: The gas was the issue, thanks! Even though gas is set low on my private net, it still became an issue when sending transactions.